# Android: License, what do I need for complete waiver of liabilities

Tags: android, licensing

If I release an app on the market, paid or unpaid, what license agreement is valid between me and the user? Is there a standard eula which applies for all apps unless otherwise stated? Do I have to create my own license?

I don't want to give away the source code, so GPL is not an option. I don't mind people copying it. I want to waive all responsiblities and liabilites as much as leagally possible (like the GPL does). What shall I do?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [Android Developer Distribution Agreement](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html). It states:

> 5.4 You grant to the user a non-exclusive, worldwide, and perpetual license to perform, display, and use the Product on the Device. If you choose, you may include a separate end user license agreement (EULA) in your Product that will govern the user's rights to the Product in lieu of the previous sentence.

So you're giving the user the right to use the product. If you think it's necessary to include further legal protections, you have the option to include a EULA that describes them.

You've probably noticed that most apps don't have a EULA.

A [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+end+user+license+agreement) shows [this page about how to add a EULA to your app](http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/adding-eula-to-android-app/).

Oh, and you're not bound by any agreement, like the GPL, to release the source code for your app. So you don't have to do that if you don't want to.

(Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.)

Comment: the first link is basically the eula for the developer. I wonder if the end user has _no_ additional eula and your app freezes the phone, you miss an important call and lose money because of that. Is the developer liable?